# Attach all CSV files in a folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm running a script to automatically send emails with attachments. All attachments will have a `.csv` extension.

I do not know the name of the files before hand. I am using the `Dir` statement.

I tried breaking the `Dir` statement into different strings, but that was not working either.

```vb
Dim cAttachment As String
Dim Folder As String
Dim fileCriteria As String

Folder = "C:\Users\____\Desktop\Test Folder"
fileCriteria = ".csv"
cAttachment = Dir(Folder & "\*" & fileCriteria)
```

I also tried:

```
Dim cAttachment As String 
cAttachment = Dir("C:\Users\___\Desktop\Test Folder\*.csv")
```

I get

> expected end of statement

on the leading parenthesis of my `Dir` statement.

Comment: This code does not cause "expected end of statement error".

Comment: Do you have another function or Variable with the name `Dir` elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should be*

> ```
> Folder = "C:\Users\____\Desktop\Test Folder\"
> cAttachment = Dir(Folder & "*.csv")`
>
>     '// Loop to attch
>     Do While Len(cAttachment ) > 0
>         .Attachments.Add Folder & cAttachment 
>         Atmt_File = Dir
>     Loop
> ```
>
> ---

*Full Example code*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Atmt_Path As String
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim rng As Object
    Dim Atmt_File As String

    '// Attachments Path.
    Atmt_Path = "C:\Temp\"

    '// Create the message.
    Set olMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olMsg
        .Display        '// This line must be retained

        Atmt_File = Dir(Atmt_Path & "*.csv")

        '// Loop to attch
        Do While Len(Atmt_File) > 0
            .Attachments.Add Atmt_Path & Atmt_File
            Atmt_File = Dir
        Loop

        '// Cancell email if no files to send
        If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "There are no reports to attach.", vbInformation
            .Close 0
            .Delete
        Else

            '// Add the To recipient(s)
            Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add("0m3r@email.com")
            Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add("0m3r@email.com")
            olRecip.Type = olTo

            '// Add the CC recipient(s)
            Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add("0m3r@email.com")
            olRecip.Type = olCC

            '// Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
            .Subject = "Reports - " & Format(Now, "Long Date")
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh        '// High importance
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

            '// Edit the message body.
            Set olInsp = .GetInspector
            Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor

            '// Set message body (to retain the signature)
            Set rng = wdDoc.Range(0, 0)

            '// add the text to message body
            rng.Text = "Files are Attached, Thank you" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf


            '// Resolve each Recipient's name.
            For Each olRecip In .Recipients
                olRecip.Resolve
                If Not olRecip.Resolve Then
                    olMsg.Display
                End If

            Next
'            .Send '//This line optional
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! It creates the email, attaches the required attachment but the email does not send.. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve your result without having to use the old `Dir()` `Function`. To do that you need to use `"Scripting.FileSystemObject"`.

This is the code to discover **all files** with `.csv` extension in a specific folder:

```
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object  

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\my\Folder\") 'Set this accordingly
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

'For all files in the folder
For Each oFile In oFiles
    If (oFile Like "*.csv") Then
        'Add this file to attachments
        objMessage.AddAttachment oFile.Path
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. I ended up switching to a powershell script though.

Comment: I agree `Dir` is old fashioned and `Scripting.FileSystemObject` has more functionaility. But why do you think: "The Dir() Function doesn't allow you to list all files in a directory."?

Comment: @Louis But, we have to use a `For Each` loop with an `If` check anyway - I would have considered `Do Until` to be *more* practical in this situation (even though I normally prefer `For` loops!)

Comment: @Chronocidal How is `Do Until` more practical? You still have to check for two conditions and in this way the code is *more* readable.

Comment: @Lous Because you no longer need to examine non-csv files?  `cAttachment = Dir(Folder & "\*.csv"): Do Until Len(cAttachment)<4: objMessage.Attachments.Add Folder & "\" & cAttachment, 1, 1: cAttachment= Dir(): Loop`

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, but like I was saying, that code is much *less* readable than mine. *Compactness* is not always the solution if you sacrifice *readability*.

Comment: @Louis ***shrug***  To each his own - I, personally, find both versions (once properly linespaced instead of one-lined with `:` as required in comments) to be equally readable:  "Get the first file, and then (until we run out of files) attach the file and get the next one" seems simple enough